# Integrated terminal in VSCode not allowing me to use zsh

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

I am running VSCode 1.87.2 on Pop!_OS 22.0.4, kernel version 6.6.10-76060610-generic

**UPDATED**

A lot of commands (such as `sudo`,`apt`,`docker`) do not work when in the integrated shell in VS Code. Example response: `bash: sudo: command not found`

When I type the full path to say `apt` I get this:

```
$ mmurphy@pop-os:~$ /usr/bin/apt
$ bash: /usr/bin/apt: No such file or directory
```

## Integrated terminal (VSCode) not recognizing commands that work in standalone Terminal app

I recently reinstalled the OS and I did not install anything other than VS Code and Chrome.

*Note* before I got new hardware and installed 22.0.4 on it I had been using 21 with it being my primary dev environment so I had using the integrated shell for a long time.

Comment: I was just using `packer` as an example, same behavior with `ansible`, `terraform`, `zsh` (all of which resolve in standalone shell). Changing the path did not fix it, in the global settings that is how bash is configured: `path: bash`

Comment: I apologize for making things more confusing than they are, I definitely should not have grouped 2 questions together. I updated the original question to explicitly state environment and outcome and removed the other question

Comment: Okay but still confused on the basic problem. Is `packer` a command? Its not clear why you call this a "package". If `packer` is in your path and is an executable command it should work. What is `packer` supposed to do?

Comment: `packer`, `terraform`, etc are packages installed with `apt`. Basically no non-OS packages are available in the integrated shell in VSCode but are available in the standalone terminal that comes with Pop!_OS. When you run `packer` with no args you should see the help menu

Comment: By definition the integrated terminal should work the same in VSCode as out of it (that's what the integrated part means). I know I said not to post images but in this case can you screenshot this problem with the terminal)? Show this command "packer" and also "which packer" ... I'm a skeptic.

Comment: You can add your screenshots to a chat also!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257199/discussion-between-user1314147-and-topsail).

Comment: what if you disable shell integration in VS Code settings and then reload VS Code and try again?

Comment: I find your question a bit confusing: When you enter a command X and get as response `X: command not found`, you obviously don't have an executable named X in any of the directories listed in your PATH. So the first step for debugging would be to do a `echo $PATH` (or in zsh alternatively the slightly more readable `echo $path`) and verify that the PATH is correct.  This information needs to go into your question - otherwise there is no point in discussing it.

Comment: I would also like to know what echo $PATH provides (there is a screenshot of this in the discussion but agree it belongs in the question). Also the location of the executable of one of the commands that cannot be found, such as `packer` - we are being told it is in /usr/bin but I would like to see the verification of that, e.g., `ls -l /usr/bin/packer`

Comment: Also note that everything must be from your terminal in VSCode you are trying to use. It is basically irrelevant that it "works" in a different shell outside of VSCode - I mean that's nice and good for your other shell but we want to focus on fixing the problem in VSCode and we need to know what's happening there. However, at the end of the day you might end up borrowing or setting up some configuration in bash in a similar way that you have done for zsh (meaning, adding some configuration to .bashrc, or .profile, and so  on ... or possibly just switching your default shell in VSCode to zsh.

Comment: Finally it is possible there is some issue with configuration of the integrated terminal in VSCode although not really what I expect - I've been using the integrated terminal in VSCode on an ubuntu system for many years with no problems and usually it "just works" out of the box. Still, there may be something going on there.

Comment: That is what is really confusing me, the integrated shell in VSCode says it cannot find the command, but when I echo $PATH the directory that contains the binary is there. And to reiterate I confirm that the binary does work as it should in the standalone shell, that is simply a test step. The shell, whether it be bash or zsh, is irelevant to this issue: the bottom line is that the binary cannot be found

Comment: I updated the original answer to something that I think is more succinct slash less ambiguous

Comment: How is VSCode installed? Is it a Flatpak or is it from the system package manager?

Answer (score 1):

There have not been many [reports of this issue in VSCode](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode+bash+%22not+found%22&type=issues&s=created&o=desc), except maybe [issue 207117](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/207117): "User-defined PATH no longer sourced in remote ssh session after 1.87.1 release".

From the image you have shared [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257199/discussion-between-user1314147-and-topsail), it is clear that `packer` is working correctly when invoked from a shell outside VSCode, and you have verified its location with `which packer` showing `/usr/bin/packer`. The permission appears to be correct as well.

Test first `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, or any other relevant startup scripts are being sourced correctly (add an echo to follow their activation).
Open the preferences  (`Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`) and look for the `terminal.integrated.env.linux` and `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux` settings. There might be some environment configurations overriding the default behavior.

Also, disable any VSCode extensions that might be interacting with the terminal environment, then restart VSCode to see if the issue persists.

Check your `Terminal: Select Default Profile`, and make sure that the correct shell profile (e.g., `bash` or `zsh`) is selected.

In both the integrated terminal and the standalone terminal, run `env | sort` and compare the outputs to see if there are discrepancies in the environment variables.

Sometimes, forcing the shell to run as a login shell within VSCode can make sure all startup files are sourced correctly: modify the `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux` setting in VSCode to include `-l` (e.g., `["-l"]` for bash or zsh).